# Creating txt file based on user input in php

Tags: php, file, text

Is it possible that we get input from user and create a text file with the user defined name??
and store data whatever he wants in it??

e.g. a user wants to create a text file with the name of Book.txt and want to add some text to it...all of this should be based on Run Time

sorry if its already posted

Comment: We need to know the language you are using.

Comment: Answer is: YES. If you are on windows just use notepad - that meets all the requirements you've specified. But seriously without more info more info this question is useless. What platform? What language?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. This would involve writing a "program" using a "programming language." You'd need to

1. gather requirements
2. design the program
3. write the code
4. test the code
5. release the code

Simple!